# Swift: Getting a Parse User objectId from someone other than the current user

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I need get an objectId from a user that is not the current user. I'm able to do a PFUserQuery to get the user that I'm looking for. I can see all the data there, I just can't extract the objectId.

```
var query = PFUser.query()
            query!.whereKey("email", equalTo:userNameObject)
            query!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (newUser: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if error == nil {


                    println(newUser) //This gets the correct User Record

                    var userVariable = newUser.objectId as String //Error: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need the objected?  If you want to store a reference to that user in another object you can just assign the `PFUser` reference directly.

Comment: @Paulw11 These people never worked with a ORM or such a badass backend :P

Answer (score 0):

In the above code, `newUser` is an array, not a `PFUser` object. If you're guaranteed to only get 0 or 1 user from your query, then you should use `getFirstObjectInBackground` rather than `findObjectsinBackground`.

Try the following:

```
var query = PFUser.query()!
query.whereKey("email", equalTo:userNameObject)
query.getFirstObjectInBackground { newUser, error in
  if error == nil {
    println(newUser)
    var userVariable = newUser.objectId as String
  }  
}
```